# Spectral Measures: Concentration

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider spectral measures:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad E(\mathbb{C})=1$$

Define its support:
$$\operatorname{supp}(E):=\bigg(\bigcup_{U=\mathring{U}:E(U)=0}U\bigg)^\complement=\bigcap_{C=\overline{C}:E(C)=1}C$$

By second countability:
$$E\bigg(\operatorname{supp}E^\complement\bigg)\varphi=E\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B_k'\right)\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E(B_k')\varphi=0$$

> But it may happen:
>   $$\Omega\subsetneq\operatorname{supp}E:\quad E(\Omega)=E(\operatorname{supp}E)=1$$

What is an example?

Comment: If the spectral measure is defined on $\mathbb{C}$, then the spectrum of $\int \lambda dE(\lambda)$ is the the support of $E$. For $\mu \notin\mbox{supp} E$ you can write down the resolvent $(\int \lambda dE(\lambda)-\mu I)^{-1}=\int(\lambda-\mu)^{-1}dE(\lambda)$

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yepp... and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue iff $E(\{\lambda\})\neq 0$. So can one construct an example with $\mathrm{supp}E=[0,1]$ but also $E((0,1])=1$. For nonseparable Hilbert spaces I have this construction in mind by just "filling up" with eigenvalues for all $z\in(0,1]$. But I cannot imagine yet what else would work...

Comment: @Freeze_S Why does the example I give below not work?

Comment: @user161825: Ah right yes that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the operator $(Af)(x)=xf(x)$ on the Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$ with Lebesgue measure. Then $E_A(M)=1_M$ is the spectral measure associated with $A$. Note that $\mbox{supp }E_A=\sigma(A)=[0,1]$, but $E_A(\{\lambda\})=0$ for any singleton $\lambda$, since $A$ does not have any eigenvalues. Now consider, say, the set $(0,1]$, for which $I=E([0,1])=E(\{0\})+E((0,1])=E((0,1])$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your spectral measure is defined on Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, which is the standard definition of the spectral measure which is the spectral resolution for a normal operator $T$.

You have defined the support $\mbox{supp}E$ to be the intersection of all closed subsets $C$ for which $E(C)=I$. If $E(A)=I$ for some closed subset $A\subsetneq \mbox{supp}E$, then $A$ is one of the sets in your intersection, yielding an obvious contradiction.

If $\mbox{supp}E$ is contained in some closed disk of finite radius $R$, then $T_{E}=\int \lambda dE(\lambda)$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
        \|T_{E}x\|^{2} & = \int_{\mbox{supp}E} |\lambda|^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2} \\
              & \le \int_{\mbox{supp}E}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2}R^{2} = \|E(\mbox{supp}E)x\|^{2}R^{2} = R^{2}\|x\|^{2}.
\end{align}
$$
So $\|T_{E}\| \le \|R\|$.

Comment: The point was rather to have a not necessarily closed $A\in\Sigma$ with $E(A)=1$ but $A\subsetneq\mathrm{supp}E$.

Comment: By the way thanks for the nice quick proof of boundedness :)

Comment: Yes, it's obvious that $E(\mbox{supp}E\setminus\{\lambda\})=E(\mbox{supp}E)$ for some $\lambda \in \mbox{supp}E$ iff $E(\{\lambda\})= 0$. I thought you surely must be asking something else.

Comment: Yes I edited my question what I looked for is a nonclosed subset

Comment: Same remark applies. $E(\mbox{supp}E\setminus F)=E(\mbox{supp}E)$ for some $F \subseteq\mbox{supp}E$ iff $E(F)=0$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : In terms of the operator $T_{E}=\int \lambda dE(\lambda)$, one has $\sigma(T_{E})=\mbox{supp}E$, which means that there exists such a set $F$ iff there exists $\lambda \in\sigma(T_{E})$ which is not in the point spectrum of $T_{E}$ (assuming your spectral measure is defined on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ and not some general measurable space.)

Comment: Yepp so one only needs to find an operator with a spectral value not being an eigenvalue. I guess the Laplacian on the real line would serve as an example...